# Install Windows 11 on Ubuntu VM

Tags: system-installation, windows-11

1 - system:Ubuntu 20.04.6
2 - Instructions: following Ubuntu <https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-a-windows-11-vm-using-lxd#1-overview>
3 - distrobuilder installed successfully.
4 - additional tools installed successfully.
5 - distrobuilder repack-windows : error message

```
root@# distrobuilder repack-windows Downloads/Win11.iso Win11.lxd.iso
INFO[2023-08-31T11:20:51+01:00] Mounting Windows ISO                         
mount: /var/cache/distrobuilder.2848722701/source: WARNING: device write-protected, mounted read-only.
INFO[2023-08-31T11:20:51+01:00] Downloading drivers ISO  
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
final report
99.99% done, estimate finish Thu Aug 31 11:28:29 2023
Total translation table size: 2048
Total rockridge attributes bytes: 0
Total directory bytes: 217088
Path table size(bytes): 2464
Max brk space used e9000
2980290 extents written (5820 MB)
INFO[2023-08-31T11:28:32+01:00] Removing cache directory  

file repacked on lxd not found !!
```